# Can polymer app-route be used to create a catch all route?

Tags: polymer, app-router

Is there a way to use app-route to create a catch all route?

Adding wild card doesn't seem to work the way I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is possible as of **v0.9.2** of `app-route`. The [`fallbackSelection`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#property-fallbackSelection) attribute on `iron-pages` might work for you.

If you have a different use case than what's described in [this issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route/issues/68), I suggest opening a new issue within the [Github project](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route).